# Как связать слайдер UI в Юнити и Plygame?

Tags: unity3d

Я работаю с плагином *Plygame*. Делаю персонажа и не могу понять, как привязать его `здоровье и ману` к слайдеру на сцене. С помощью слайдера, я хочу показывать оставшийся процент.

Как его задать через плагин и задавать его значение там?

Моя иерархия игрока:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то надо что-то типа такого:

в `plyBlox` в разделе `Common` → `Object`  есть такая штучка как `Set property value`. Скорее всего нужно пользоваться именно ей. 
Там в этом компоненте есть поле, куда можно закинуть этот объект со сцены. Затем кликнув на "именование объекта" в **этом самом блоке**, появится меню, где можно выбрать компонент, установленный на данном объекте (UISlider),
а у данного компонента можно выбрать нужное свойство. Вот как в итоге может выглядеть это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]